# spark specify multiple jars for azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-storage

Im trying to access azure blobs from my spark-shell but get the following error-

```
scala> sc.textFile("wasb://mycontainer@test.blob.core.windows.net/testfolder/txtfile").count()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/azure/storage/StorageException
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1064)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1035)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2397)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)\
```

multiple jar in the jars directive

```
Ps-M:spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 p$ bin/spark-shell --jars "/Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar" "/Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar"
```

I would like to know how to specify multiple jars in the --jars directive, right now I mentioned as "jar1" "jar2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple JARs are separated by comma.

Try to run

```
Ps-M:spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7 p$ bin/spark-shell --jars "/Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar,/Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar"
```

Also, make sure `com/microsoft/azure/storage/StorageException` class is in the above JARS. You can run following to check that:

```
jar -tvf /Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar | grep -i com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException

jar -tvf /Users/p/Documents/ba/spark-tutorial/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar | grep -i com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException
```

If you cannot find StorageException class in above 2 JARS then look for the JARS which has this class and add to `--jars` option.

Hope this helps